# MongoDB performing COLLSCAN even with an index specified in the compound index

Tags: mongodb

I have a database with the following compound index `NameHandleCreationTime`

```
        "metadata" : {
            "formatVersion" : 8,
            "infoObj" : "{ \"v\" : 2, \"key\" : { \"Name\" : 1, \"Handle\" : 1, \"CreationTime\" : -1 }, \"name\" : \"NameHandleCreationTime\", \"ns\" : \"intenv.UserCollection_test\", \"collation\" : { \"locale\" : \"en\", \"caseLevel\" : false, \"caseFirst\" : \"off\", \"strength\" : 1, \"numericOrdering\" : false, \"alternate\" : \"non-ignorable\", \"maxVariable\" : \"punct\", \"normalization\" : false, \"backwards\" : false, \"version\" : \"57.1\" } }"
        },
...
```

So I thought if I make a query with `Name: xyz` to get a single document from the `UserCollection`, I'd get it through an IXSCAN, because the compound index's first field is `Name`. However, the logs show that I am COLLSCANing and even winning plan is a COLLSCAN.

```
//db.getCollection("intenv.UserCollection_test").find({Name:"xyz"}).collation({locale:"en"}).explain()
{
    "queryPlanner" : {
        "plannerVersion" : 1,
        "namespace" : "intenv.UserCollection_test",
        "indexFilterSet" : false,
        "parsedQuery" : {
            "Name" : {
                "$eq" : "xyz"
            }
        },
        "collation" : {
            "locale" : "en",
            "caseLevel" : false,
            "caseFirst" : "off",
            "strength" : 3,
            "numericOrdering" : false,
            "alternate" : "non-ignorable",
            "maxVariable" : "punct",
            "normalization" : false,
            "backwards" : false,
            "version" : "57.1"
        },
        "winningPlan" : {
            "stage" : "COLLSCAN",
            "filter" : {
                "Name" : {
                    "$eq" : "xyz"
                }
            },
            "direction" : "forward"
        },
        "rejectedPlans" : [ ]
    },
...
```

What is going on...?
Also, I toyed around with collation (https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/collation/) while writing this question: setting `collation({  locale: "en", strength: 1})` gives me an IXSCAN as the winning plan...

Why is this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The collation requested in the query is different than the collation the index was created with, so it can't be used for that query.